# Does C99 assume that subnormal numbers are supported?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, ieee-754

Does C99 assume that subnormal numbers are supported?

From:

- the presence of `FP_SUBNORMAL` classification macro
- the fact that in IEEE 754 support of subnormal numbers is required

I make the conclusion that subnormal numbers are supported in C99. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: what do you mean by "supported"? what features are required?

Comment: Do you ask if the C99 __language__ itself supports subnormal number? I can say "I have a car" in English, it doesn't mean I really have it... Or do you ask if when you compile your compiler can operate using subnormal numbers?

Comment: *"the fact that in IEEE 754 support of subnormal numbers is required"* What is the source of that statement?

Comment: @user694733: IEEE 754 is a document that specifies floating-point arithmetic, and that specification includes subnormal numbers. So IEEE 754 is the source of that statement. More specifically, it is IEEE Std 754-2019. Encodings for subnormal numbers in binary formats are specified in clause 3.4. Their use and appearance in arithmetic follows largely implicitly from the specifications of operations elsewhere in the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does C99 assume that subnormal numbers are supported?

No. [5.2.4.2.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.2.4.2.2). The language defines a model of a floating point number. Then the language defines what is a subnormal floating point *within that model*. Then an interface is established how to detect and work with subnormal floating point numbers and how are they handled in corner cases - I mean, when exceptions are raised and when not.

It does not mean, that the underlying architecture uses this model to represent floating point numbers. The intention is to write the standard in an [abstract](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.2.3p1) way, trying to provide an interface without requiring how it should be implemented. [Note 16](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#note16):

> 16. The floating-point model is intended to clarify the description of each floating-point characteristic and does not require the floating-point arithmetic of the implementation to be identical.

If the implementation *implements* [Annex F](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#F), **then** the floating types match the formats described in IEC 60559, so it will have subnormal numbers. This is recommended practice, but optional, detected with a macro - there is no requirement.

> the presence of FP_SUBNORMAL classification macro

There may be more `FP_[A-Z]*` macros provided by implementation for additional "kinds of floating point values".

> the fact that in IEEE 754 support of subnormal numbers is required

But C does not require IEEE 754 support.

Comment: "detected with a macro". Specifically, the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro.

Comment: If IEEE 754 does not require support of subnormal numbers, then why it prescribes _Implementations shall provide the following non-computational operations_ ... _boolean isSubnormal(source) -- isSubnormal(x) is true if and only if x is subnormal_? Can you elaborate on `IEEE 754 does not require support of subnormal numbers`?

Comment: Och, the last part is wrong. I meant that C does not require IEEE754, which means that C does not require subnormal numbers... :/